# Curl chmod file transfer

Tags: php, file-upload, curl

Group,
  I am facing a problem with curl file transfer. I have one form in a site A. The form collects some data and also a file (file upload). When that form gets submitted it stores the data in the site A and also stores the data in site B( another server ). The data are getting saved from server A to server B. But the file transfer with curl has file permission problem. My file need to have 0777 chmod for the curl to read and transfer.

What I do is I read the file with

```
chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)));
```

from site A and transfer that data to site B (another server). If i change the permission in site A's file that needed to be read,  through shell as a root, chmod 777, and make a curl transfer then it is getting stored perfectly in server B. But when i make a file transfer through a code then i could not use chmod function because the file is stored as a "apache" in user but not as a "root".

### Detailed explanation:

I have a joomla site with a enquiry form in chronoform. I have some text and also one file upload in the chrnoform. When a user asks for a quote, those data need to stored in a sugerCRM (sugarCRM leads module, web to leads form, campaign). Joomla site is in server A and sugarCRM is in server B. The uploaded file will be stored in the notes table (mysql) of sugarCRM. All worked if i manually change the file to chmode 777. But i want it happen when some one upload the file in the chronoform. I tried chmod through a php code but it does not work because the program that creates the file will have  "apache" as a user not as "root" user. Any workaround? I just need to know if changing the file permission from 0644 to 0777 through program. Any help? If anyone wants to see the code then i could pastebin the code and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

That file that changes the permissions will need to have the same permissions as the account you use to change it manually. you can give apache or www-data persmissions to make changes to certain files/directories (or sudo) but i do not recommend it.